# Is there anything special about console windows efficiency/hardware-wise?

Tags: console

Just out of curiosity, do console windows actually utilize legacy text-modes of computers' graphics cards, or do they just use regular graphics card features under the hood? Would there ever be a reason that somebody would choose a console window over a GUI created using a graphics library, like OpenGL, for performance reasons?

Comment: Console windows are designed primarily to display text, using a fixed font. That's why they're console windows and not GUI windows. It's also why console editors don't mix several fonts or allow you to insert WYSIWYG character formatting or graphics. There would never be a reason to choose console over a GUI window when designing a GUI.

Comment: @KenWhite But there are some cases when a program just needs to receive data and output modified versions of the data. Either a GUI or a console application could work for such cases.

Comment: And that data is typically not graphics (at least not that are displayed in a console window). You can send and receive all the data you want with either of them, but that's not what you asked about here. The difference is when **displaying content**, and that's what you asked about (when asking about the graphics card and GUI).. If you don't need a graphic UI, you can use either. If you need a GUI, don't use the console, because it's a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared two console windows in different computers that each use Windows 10. The computers' fonts seemed to be different which seems to suggest that console windows do indeed seem to use the graphics card's native text-rendering mode (or at least the card's font).

Compare this image of a console window that I found on the internet (you can see that windows 10 is being used by looking at the icons below the console window):
[Windows 10 Console Window](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiozab_vsTbAhUFzlkKHXPJAagQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F235101%2F10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10%2F&psig=AOvVaw0HDa56cEcXFdUnc68d8MGT&ust=1528561908988521)

to my console window (displaying the same text):
[image]

Note things such as the fact that the capital letter 'D' on my computer does not have the letter's curve extend beyond it's vertical line.